# Is it possible to do a logical AND in this jquery code?

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

here's a question for the logically endowed. I'm using **[isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)**, a badass jquery mozaic tool that does, among other awesome things, animated [filtering](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/filtering.html) of data via code like this ...

```
    $('#container').isotope({ filter: '.metal' });
```

You can also do an AND for multiple selectors ...

```
    $('#container').isotope({ filter: '.alkali, .alkaline-earth' });
```

... where anything with class `alkali` **OR** class `alkaline-earth` are selected.

I'm looking for a way to filter the "logical AND" (aka "logical conjunction"), showing ONLY elements where BOTH `alkalai` **AND** `alkaline-earth` classes exist.

I found this stackoverflow answer ... [How do I combine logical OR with logical AND within a jQuery attribute selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404995/how-do-i-combine-logical-or-with-logical-and-within-a-jquery-attribute-selector) ... but isotope probably needs something more specific in the filter parameter.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```
$('#container').isotope({ filter: '.alkali.alkaline-earth' });
```

That's the common way to select elements that have both class names defined.